Dart how to calculate, limit a sync function runtime
I have code like this:
  final s = DartFormatter().format('''
main() {
  $str;
}
''');

The variable $str is sometimes very large, so format() can sometimes take a long time to run.
Can I limit the runtime of format()?

You could run the operation in a separate isolate and kill it (https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.4.4/dart-isolate/Isolate/kill.html) if you don't get the async message back before a deadline.
